# Public IP configuration on Home router ( TP-link 940N)

Tags: router, email, dns, ip, nat

I got 196.188.173.32/30 ip adress from my ISP with the following configuration.

```
 Wan ip : 10.126.10.158/29
 Gateway : 10.12.10.157
```

```
Lan Ip : 196.188.173.32/30
```

I have configured the router per the ISP, and other people can access my server remotely without issue.

But when I make a connection to other websites, they see a different source IP. E.i it shall have been 196.188.173.33 but they see 196.188.150.250( ISP )

Due to this problem I couldn't send email that reach the inbox, due to PTR record mismatch

Comment: Have you got those addresses the right way round? 10.x.x.x is a private [LAN] address, but 196.188.173.x belongs to Ethio Telecom in Addis Ababa, Ethiopia. You can't use an assigned private IP address range as a LAN address, it will cause no end of issues. Your ISP should give you one WAN IP address, probably dynamic, so it could change every day or every decade & you have no control over that.

Comment: Yes I got it that way and it perfectly  works  for incoming  connection, but when I make an outgoing connection  my ip chnages to another  ip that i dont own.

Comment: You don't 'own' your external IP address. Your internal address is also badly wrong. You really should never use a public address inside your own LAN, you should have 192.168.x.x or other [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) which is designed for that. If your external is really a 10.x.x.x address, then you are behind [CG-NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), which means you will not be able to route anything from the outside world back to your computer.